# How To call An Action In Umbraco Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, umbraco, umbraco7

I created an Umbraco `DocumentType` with the alias `Personal` and created a controller that inherits

> Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController

I added two `Action`s, one is the default action and the other is called `Test`.

How can I fire the `Test` Action from the `Personal` controller?

```
public class PersonalController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    // GET: Personal
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        return base.Index(model);
    }

    public String Test(RenderModel model)
    {
        return "fff";
    }
}
```

When I put the url like this: `localHost/personal/test` it shows:

> No umbraco document matches the url '/test'.

Which is right, so how can I call it?

Comment: You create a new controller, inherit from SurfaceController and call it like /umbraco/surface/{controller}/{action}

Comment: /umbraco/RenderMvc Shows before the route why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitSearchForm(SearchViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchTerm))
        {
            model.SearchTerm = model.SearchTerm;
            model.SearchGroups = GetSearchGroups(model);
            model.SearchResults = _searchHelper.GetSearchResults(model, Request.Form.AllKeys);
        }
        return RenderSearchResults(model.SearchResults);
    }
    return null;
}

public ActionResult RenderSearchResults(SearchResultsModel model)
{
    return PartialView(PartialViewPath("_SearchResults"), model);
}
```

See this blog post for the full context behind where this code snippet came from.

http://www.codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-search-by-document-type-and-property-in-umbraco/

Comment: one more Question can a is a session is created in a view using rezor can it be seen by the back end controller and how ?

Comment: Sorry IbraHim, I can't understand what you are asking here.